# Can the REDDIT Api be used to send a PM to another Reddit user?

Tags: message, reddit

I have been looking at the REDDIT api documentation, and just by looking at it, it seems that one CANNOT(?) send a PM message to another Reddit user.  Please, prove me wrong :)

Is it possible to see another user's subredddit subscriptions?

Thanks for any input.

Comment: Didn't even post a link to the api. Plus, I'm not going to do research for you.

Comment: @hyleaus this is aimed at folks that are familiar with the REDDIT api.  I have the basics figured out..

Comment: Viewed more than 1700 times and not a single upvote?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can send PMs through reddit's API with [compose](http://www.reddit.com/dev/api#POST_api_compose).

You cannot see other users' subreddit subscriptions.

Depending on the language you are using, you may want to look at existing [API libraries](https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/API%3A-Third-Party-Clients). In my experience [PRAW](https://github.com/praw-dev/praw/wiki) for python is the most feature-complete (disclosure: I am the package maintainer).

Comment: What is happening when you must enter captcha? Can you get url of the image so we can display it in app?